# Replace cell values in data frame based on column name and variable match

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the value in a data frame cell based on the column name matching a row variable, as in the example code.  I know enough to know that the nested loop is not the preferred way to do this (and that a more efficient solution is probably quite simple), but haven't been able to figure out a clean vectorized approach.  I've been messing with nested apply, i.e., an apply inside a function called by apply, but haven't been successful, nor does that seem like it would be the best way, either.

Input:

```
test.df
  Group         G1        G2         G3
1    G1 0.63910462 0.5738143 0.97428347
2    G2 0.62578294 0.4653417 0.92010090
3    G3 0.01136336 0.3163722 0.20266664
4    G1 0.09054996 0.1984567 0.17488220
5    G2 0.74865266 0.9862222 0.80725355
6    G3 0.82855980 0.2668529 0.06786335
7    G1 0.74310410 0.8861169 0.44801963
8    G2 0.97329786 0.6682355 0.69658779
9    G3 0.68696020 0.7362139 0.77452962
```

Output:

```
test.df
  Group         G1        G2        G3
1    G1         NA 0.5738143 0.9742835
2    G2 0.62578294        NA 0.9201009
3    G3 0.01136336 0.3163722        NA
4    G1         NA 0.1984567 0.1748822
5    G2 0.74865266        NA 0.8072535 
6    G3 0.82855980 0.2668529        NA
7    G1         NA 0.8861169 0.4480196
8    G2 0.97329786        NA 0.6965878
9    G3 0.68696020 0.7362139        NA
```

Code:

```
test.df <- data.frame("Group"=rep(c("G1", "G2", "G3"), 3), "G1"=runif(9, 0, 1), "G2"=runif(9, 0, 1), "G3" = runif(9,0,1))

for (j in 1:ncol(test.df)) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(test.df)) {
    if(colnames(test.df)[j] == test.df$Group[i]) {
      test.df[i,j] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```

I think I could use dplyr filter to get the values that need to be replaced, replace them, and then reassemble the data frame, but I'm interested in learning other options.

Comment: Just to make certain I am understanding your code correctly: what you are seeking to do, for example, is eliminate all the values where row and column name are equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorize it with `match()`.

```
idx <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(test.df)), match(test.df$Group, names(test.df)[-1]))
test.df[-1][idx] <- NA
```

`idx` creates the index matrix to use for gathering the values we want to convert to NA.  The first part is just a sequence the length of the number of rows. The second part matches the `Group` column with the names of the other columns.  Then we replace.

This results in the updated `test.df`

```
Group         G1        G2        G3
1    G1         NA 0.5738143 0.9742835
2    G2 0.62578294        NA 0.9201009
3    G3 0.01136336 0.3163722        NA
4    G1         NA 0.1984567 0.1748822
5    G2 0.74865266        NA 0.8072535
6    G3 0.82855980 0.2668529        NA
7    G1         NA 0.8861169 0.4480196
8    G2 0.97329786        NA 0.6965878
9    G3 0.68696020 0.7362139        NA
```

**Note:**  I had `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in my creation of `test.df`, so in yours you will have to use `test.df$Group <- as.character(test.df$Group)` first since your example has it as factors.

Comment: I got far enough to reorder and gather up by group doing this: `test.df <- test.df[order(test.df$Group), ]` and did not know how to go to next level. Now, it makes total sense. In fact, I did not even need to order it. Wow.

Answer (score 2):

You could split rows and then sub-assign:

```
s = split(seq_len(nrow(test.df)), test.df$Group)
for (k in names(s)) test.df[s[[k]], k] <- NA_real_
```

Or with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
for (k in names(s)) set(test.df, i = s[[k]], j = k, v = NA_real_)
```

Note that you don't actually have to use a data.table here; we're using `set` on a data.frame. The advantage of `set` in this case is its modification by reference.

Comment: I suspect this is a dupe question, but wasn't able to find a target.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the Baton:

```
test.df %>% mutate(G1 = ifelse(Group == "G1", NA, G1))

#   Group         G1        G2        G3
# 1    G1         NA 0.3337749 0.3999944
# 2    G2 0.25801678 0.4763512 0.3253522
# 3    G3 0.47854525 0.8921983 0.7570871
# 4    G1         NA 0.8643395 0.2026923
# 5    G2 0.08424691 0.3899895 0.7111212
# 6    G3 0.87532133 0.7773207 0.1216919
# 7    G1         NA 0.9606180 0.2454885
# 8    G2 0.83944035 0.4346595 0.1433044
# 9    G3 0.34668349 0.7125147 0.2396294
```

Now, how do I get the mutate to sweep through all the columns?